# How to store a component and render conditionally

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, react-ref

I'm using material-ui popover component wrapping a formik form. it's obvious every time it is closed, the form re renders and all values get cleaned.

I thought about storing values in parent, but it's more complicated and I'm using dynamic component, then it's not a solution here.

I am looking for a way to get a copy of `children` and just show it inside popover.

Here is my code:

```
export default function ButtonPopover({ icon: Icon, children }) {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);

  const open = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const close = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <IconButton onClick={open}>
        <Icon />
      </IconButton>
      <Popover
        open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        onClose={close}
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: "bottom",
          horizontal: "center",
        }}
        transformOrigin={{
          vertical: "top",
          horizontal: "center",
        }}
      >
        // Here is what I need to be saved.
        {children}
      </Popover>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do but this is how you render conditionally:

```
export default function ButtonPopover({ icon: Icon, children }) {
    const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);

    const open = (event) => {
        setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    };

    const close = () => {
        setAnchorEl(null);
    };

    const renderChildren = () => {
        if (myCondition == true) {
            return (
                <>
                    <Text>render when condition equals true</Text>
                </>
            )
        } else {
            return (
                <>
                    <Text>render when condition doesn't equal true</Text>
                </>
            )
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
            <IconButton onClick={open}>
                <Icon />
            </IconButton>
            <Popover
                open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
                anchorEl={anchorEl}
                onClose={close}
                anchorOrigin={{
                    vertical: "bottom",
                    horizontal: "center",
                }}
                transformOrigin={{
                    vertical: "top",
                    horizontal: "center",
                }}
            >
                {renderChildren()}
            </Popover>
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I know how to render things conditionally. Actually `Popover` component does this with `open` prop itself. I just want to "Store" child component and stop it from unmounting every time the condition value changes.